# C# deserialize selected properties in json

Tags: c#, json

Given the following JSON

```
{
 "enabled": true,
 "name": "Name",
 "description": "Test",
 "rules": [
   {
      "propA": "a",
      "propB": "b"
   }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible in C# to deserialize on selected properties based on an input list:
`var propertiesToInclude = new List<string> { "description", "rules.PropA" };`

The example json is a simplified example, the real one can contain hundred of properties. The use case is to only return the fields that matches the input list in a dynamic or anonymous object and discard the other properties.

Comment: Why would you only deserialize selected fields? You could also just deserialize the entire object into a DTO and then select the data you need from it at runtime

Comment: There is no `rules.PropA` there is only `rules[x].PropA` because `rules` is an array ... also deserialize to what?

Comment: You could potentially pull out individual values from the json based on a list of inputs if that's what you mean? Depending on how dynamic the json is you might need to make it recursive.

Answer (score -1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var propertiesToInclude = new List<string> { "description", "rules.PropA" };
var splitted = propertiesToInclude.SelectMany(x => x.Split('.'));

string text = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
var json = JToken.Parse(text);

Process(json);
Console.WriteLine(json);

void Process(JToken token)
{
    if (token is JObject jObject)
    {
        jObject.Properties()
            .Where(x => !splitted.Contains(x.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => x.Remove());

        foreach (var x in jObject)
            Process(x.Value);
    }
    else if (token is JArray jArray)
    {
        foreach (var x in jArray)
            Process(x);
    }
}
```

This code on the data shown will give the desired result.
The output is a JToken object containing the desired properties.

However, I used a simple search for all occurrences of names in a splited array. This will give false positives if, for example, the root object contains the `propA` property or the object in the array contains the `description` property.

To avoid this, you need to compare the `JToken.Path` property with the `propertiesToInclude` elements, taking into account the depth.